# How to solve controller multi arument form in Angular?

Tags: angularjs

I have about 10 controllers and 20 services.

Each controller uses at least 5 the same services and modules. For example:

```
app.controller('GroupsCtrl', function(
        $rootScope,
        $scope,
        service1,
        service2,
        service3,
        service4,
        service5,
        service6,
         ...
         service20

                )
        { /**/}
```

It seems pretty ugly and messy.

Is Angular provide any solution that will solve multi argument problem? For example new form:

```
app.controller('GroupsCtrl', function(
            $rootScope,
            $scope,
            SomeObject, // goes here that contains other absent services

            service6,
             ...
             service20

                    )
            { /**/}
```

And `SomeObject` will install absent services:

```
   SomeObject:[
         service1,
        service2,
        service3,
        service4,
        service5,
        ]
```

So after that all my 10 controllers can inherit `SomeObject` instead to write full list each time.

Hope it was clear,

Thanks,

Comment: are you using ngRoute or ui-router? It's possible to apply @Mathews posted below and move specific services to route definitions using the resolve property. Each property on resolve can be an injectable function as well (it can ask for service dependencies).

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can. Create a factory which returns the services you want and use that factory in your controllers to access the services. 
Ex.

```
var myapp = angular.module('myapp', []);
myapp.service('service1', function() {
    this.test = function(){
        console.log("Inside service1 -->test");
        //alert("Inside service1 -->test")
    }

});
myapp.service('service2', function() {
    this.test = function(){
        console.log("Inside service2 -->test");
        //alert("Inside service2 -->test");
    }

});
myapp.factory('servicesFactory', function(service1,service2) {
    return {
        service1 : service1,
        service2 : service2        
        };

});


myapp.controller('Ctrl', function ($scope,servicesFactory) {
    servicesFactory.service1.test();
    servicesFactory.service2.test();

});
```

Answer (score 0):

One simple solution can be using the $inject property annotation to inject the array of service names and referr the services using the arguments array as below.

```
//Common services array
var commonServices = ['$scope','$http'];
function initiateCtl(services){
    this.scope = services[0]; this.http = services[1]; 
}

//Controller 1
var sampleCtrl = function(){
    initiateCtl(arguments);
    var $window = arguments[2];
    console.log(scope);    
};
sampleCtrl['$inject'] = commonServices.concat(['$window']);
app.controller('sampleCtrl', sampleCtrl);

//Controller 2
var sampleCtrl2 = function(){
    initiateCtl(arguments);
    var $location= arguments[2];
    console.log(scope);    
};
sampleCtrl2['$inject'] = commonServices.concat(['$location']);
app.controller('sampleCtrl2', sampleCtrl2 );
```